# Importing XPS model

Tags: rigging, armature, import

I'm curious how an imported XPS model armature seems to have IK constraint already, but it has no constraint at all. So how it is possible? can I also create a rig like that without constraint? It can be animated just fine
[image: Example1]
example1

[image: example2]
example2

[image: no constraint]
no constraint

Comment: Do you have Pose Mode -> Tool -> Pose Options -> Auto IK enabled?

Comment: Oh man! that's exactly what i'm looking for, Thank you!